# Installing Magento - Error

Tags: magento

I am getting this error while installing Magento on WAMP. Any solutions?

```
a:5:{i:0;s:430:"Error in file: "C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Newsletter\data\newsletter_setup\data-upgrade-1.6.0.0-1.6.0.1.php" - SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magentodb.newsletter_subscriber' doesn't exist, query was: DELETE `main_table`  FROM `newsletter_subscriber` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `customer_entity` AS `customer` ON main_table.customer_id = customer.entity_id WHERE (customer.website_id = 0)";i:1;s:819:"#0 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(392): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('data-upgrade', false, '1.6.0.2')
#2 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(289): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installData('1.6.0.2')
#3 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(269): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyDataUpdates()
#4 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(351): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllDataUpdates()
#5 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 C:\wamp\www\magento\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}";s:3:"url";s:18:"/magento/index.php";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"/magento/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Answer (score 1):

if it is the first install, try dopping the database and then recreate it, clear cache and launch a Magento page.

if it isnt't the first install go to core_resource table and drop the line containing 'newsletter_setup' to force magento reinstall the newsletter module and run it's install scripts.

```
-----------------------------------------------
|code               | version   | data_version |
-----------------------------------------------
|newsletter_setup   | 1.6.0.2   | 1.6.0.2      |
-----------------------------------------------
```

, and after that clear cache and open magentos page.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps for above error.

Check version used at config.xml (newsletter module),is same as version used at core_resource.If it is same but problem is arise means that drop the newsletter_setup row at core resource and run the site and also confirm the "newsletter_subscriber" table is found at database.